# How to disregard the empty column in SQL Server using NEW QUERY

Tags: sql-server

How to disregard the empty column in SQL Server using NEW QUERY

Sample Table:

Table name: **Items**

```
Name     item1     item2     item3     item4     item5
------------------------------------------------------
Adan     pen       ball      eraser    paper     bag
Bea      pen                                                       
Cathy              ball      eraser                      
Dan                                    paper            
Eva      pen                 eraser
```

Scenario:

I want to select `Name` and disregard the empty column.

SAMPLE1: I select `Name=Dan`

Result:

```
Name   item4
------------
Dan    paper
```

SAMPLE2: I want to select `Name=Eva`

Result:

```
Name   item1   item3
--------------------
Eva    pen     eraser
```

SAMPLE3: I want to select `Name=Cathy`

Result:

```
Name   item2   item3
------------------------
Cathy  ball    eraser
```

SAMPLE4: I want to select `Name=Adan`

Result:

```
Name     item1     item2     item3     item4     item5
------------------------------------------------------
Adan     pen       ball      eraser    paper     bag
```

Comment: You want the number of columns in the result to be different, depending on empty fields?  That'd require dynamic SQL.

Comment: Unless you store all those names in a temp table OR use as a list and union to main table

Comment: Yes, it depend on my empty fields. Thanks @OMG Ponies for the idea. I'll search re dynamic SQL.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Storing item1, item2, ... is the wrong design. You should put the items into a separate table and create a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the edit and for the advised..

Comment: someone who can give the code on my query above?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it may be better to design your database differently, depending on what you need to do with it in the future.

However, you can dynamically create a sql query to get the output you're looking for. I'm creating a temp table #T to simulate your example table.

```
-- create sample table
create table #T (Name varchar(50), Item1 varchar(50), Item2 varchar(50), Item3 varchar(50), Item4 varchar(50), Item5 varchar(50));
insert #T values('Adan',  'pen', 'ball', 'eraser', 'paper', 'bag');
insert #T values('Bea',   'pen', '',     '',       '',      '');                                                      
insert #T values('Cathy', '',    'ball', 'eraser', '',      '');                      
insert #T values('Dan',   '',    '',     '',       'paper', '');           
insert #T values('Eva',   'pen', '',     'eraser', '',      '');

-- query parameter
declare @Name varchar(50);
set @Name = 'dan';

-- create dynamic query
declare @sql varchar(MAX);
set @sql = 'select Name, '; 
select
    @sql = @sql +
        (case when isnull(Item1, '') <> '' then 'Item1, ' else '' end) + 
        (case when isnull(Item2, '') <> '' then 'Item2, ' else '' end) + 
        (case when isnull(Item3, '') <> '' then 'Item3, ' else '' end) + 
        (case when isnull(Item4, '') <> '' then 'Item4, ' else '' end) + 
        (case when isnull(Item5, '') <> '' then 'Item5, ' else '' end) 
from #T 
where Name = @Name;

set @sql = left(@sql, len(@sql)-1) + ' from #T where Name = ''' + @Name + ''';';

-- run dynamic query
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: how to convert this to vb.net? pls help.